# Sencha how to clear hash in routes

Tags: extjs, hash, routes, sencha-touch

I want to clear hash when I use routes in sencha extjs 6. But I dont know how to do it. extjs has history.back() which allow me to use back button browser to previous hash. 
I use redirectTo() to change the hash.

```
this.redirectTo('home',true);
```

Routes controller

```
routes:{
        home:{
            action:'onMainView'
        }
,onMainView:function(){
   //show main view
}
```

It works all fine. But I need to clear the history of hash *home* because when I click on back button again I will route to *home*. I use it in my mobile project, so when pressing back button I want to make it quite the application. Therefore clear hash is needed. I read sencha doc but I can't find any solutions.

Comment: You can use following things 
**<appname>.app.redirectTo('')**
Please chk this way works & update here.